# What is the Int(A) and Cl(A) in the excluded point topology?

Tags: general-topology

I'm testing my understanding through the exercises in my topology textbook and I am unsure of the answer for this one:

Consider the excluded point topology $EPX_p$ on a set $X$. Determine the $Int(A)$ and $Cl(A)$ for sets $A$ containing $p$ and for sets $A$ not containing $p$.

My thoughts:

I know that the interior is the union of all open sets in $A$ and that the closure is the union of all closed sets in $A$. I get a little confused when I start applying this onto topologies other than the usual topology.

I'm thinking that when $p\in A$, then $Int(A)=A$ and $Cl(A)=A$. Then when $A$ does not contain $p$ $Int(A)=A-\{p\}$ and $Cl(A)=A-\{p\}$. However, I know that $A$ is not in the topology, since the topology only contains subsets that exclude p. How would that fact play a role?

Any explanations would be helpful.

Comment: If $p\in A $ then $A$ is not open in the excluded point topology, so Int($A$), which must be open, cannot be $A$

Comment: In that case then would Int(A)={0} and Cl(A)=X?

Comment: I think you have it backwards in the question:  when $p\in A $ then Int($A$)$=A\setminus \{p\}$

Comment: You're wrong about the closure.  It's the intersection of all closed sets that contain A.  In $\Bbb R$ under the usual topology, the union of all closed sets contained in $A=(0, 1)$ is $A$, which isn't even closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $p \in A$.  Then as you note, $\operatorname{int} A$ is the union of all open sets contained in $A$.  $A \setminus \{p \} \subseteq A$ is open and is clearly the largest open set contained within $A$, so $\operatorname{int} A = A \setminus \{ p \}$.

The closed sets of this topology are $\varnothing$ and the sets containing $p$.  Thus, $A$ is closed and is therefore its own closure.

Now assume $p \notin A$.  Then $A$ is open, so it is its own interior.  $A \cup \{ p \}$ is closed.  Any closed non-empty set must contain $p$, so the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$ must contain $A \cup \{p \}$.  Also, $A \cup \{ p \}$ is closed, so the intersection of all such closed sets must fall within $A \cup \{ p \}$.  Thus, $\overline{A}= A \cup \{ p \}$.